# How do I find the first and last item of an array in an Angular 7 for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am creating a list of items in an Angular for loop. This list needs to have buttons that allow the user to move the list item up or down. If the item is already at the top of the list I want to hide the button to move the item up. If the button is at the bottom of the list, I want to hide the button that would allow the user to move the item down.

Here is the HTML for the child component which describes the list item. This method won't work given that I don't have an index for the array item. I'm using the trackBy method in the parent component, however, I'm not sure if it can will apply here.

```
<div style="margin:auto; margin-right:15px;">
        <span  style="display: inline-grid;">
            <a *ngIf="expiredIncentive[i] > 0" (click)="moveUp(incentive)" title="Move-up">
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-sort-up"></i>
                </a>
                <a *ngIf="expiredIncentives[i] < expiredIncentives.length" (click)="moveDown(incentive)" title="Move-down">
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-sort-down"></i>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
```

TS

```
@Component({
    selector: 'incentive-widget',
    templateUrl: 'incentive.widget.html',
})

export class IncentiveWidget {
      @Input()
expiredIncentives: any;
```

Here is the parent component where I'm using the child 'incentive' component. I'm binding the 'expiredIncentives' via property binding so that I have access to the length of the array in the child component.

```
<incentive-widget *ngFor="let incentive of expiredIncentives;trackBy: trackByFn"
                                  [isEditMode]="true" [incentive]="incentive" [expiredIncentives]="expiredIncentives"
                                  [dealerId]="_dealerId" [isExpiredIncentive]="true" 
                                  (clickedIncentiveUp)="clickedIncentiveUp(incentive)"
                                  (clickedIncentiveDown)="clickedIncentiveDown(incentive)">
                </incentive-widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *ngFor with `first` and `last` as variables it is a `boolean`.

then you can compare this value to verify if it is the `first` or not.

```
<incentive-widget *ngFor="let incentive of expiredIncentives;trackBy: trackByFn; let first = first; let last  = last ">
```

Comment: I'm using the trackBy function in the parent component. But not sure how to use the 'first' and 'last' variable.

Comment: For example put the following code inside the incentive component ‘<span *ngIf=“first”> I’m the first element of the loop</span>’ it will shows you the fist element with this text

Comment: So trackBy will know which item is first and which is last?